# not able to rename all directories in a given path using filepath.Walk() in go

Tags: go

This is my visit function,

```
func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if !f.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }
    str := path
    if str == config.Path {
        return nil
    }
    if str == config.LatestPath {
        return nil
    }
    dir := str
    dir = strings.TrimPrefix(str, filepath.Dir("C:\\Users\\Mark\\Desktop\\testfolder\\"))
    slashes := strings.Count(dir, "\\")
    if slashes < config.PrevSlashes {
        x := len(config.Slashes) - 1
        for x > slashes {
            config.Slashes[x] = 0
            x--
        }
    }
    config.Slashes[slashes]++
    config.PrevSlashes = slashes
    prename := ""
    for k, v := range config.Slashes {
        if k != 0 {
            if k <= slashes {
                prename += strconv.Itoa(v) + "."
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(config.Slashes)
    myRegex := `(\\(?P<number>[\d\.]*))  \w`
    for i := 0; i < slashes-1; i++ {
        myRegex += `(\\(?P<number` + strconv.Itoa(i) + `>[\d\.]*))  \w*`
    }
    re := regexp.MustCompile(myRegex)
    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(dir, -1) {
        return nil
        fmt.Println(i, match)
    }
    Cdir := filepath.Dir(path)
    newpath := fmt.Sprintf("%s\\%s  %s", Cdir, prename, f.Name())
    config.LatestPath = path
    os.Rename(path, newpath)
    return nil
}
```

the folder structure looks like this

```
testfolder\a\aa\aaa, 
testfolder\a\aa\aab, 
testfolder\a\aa\aac, 
testfolder\a\ab\aaa
```

The problem that i have is filepath,Walk() does not see the changed directory names.

it first renames testfolder\a\aa\aaa to testfolder\1. a\aa\aaa and then it tries to rename testfolder\a\aa\aaa to testfolder\a\1. aa\aaa but i want it to rename testfolder\1. a\aa\aaa to testfolder\1. a\1.1. aa\aaa

the end result should look like

```
\testfolder\1. a\1.1. aa\1.1.1. aaa
\testfolder\1. a\1.1. aa\1.1.2. aab
\testfolder\1. a\1.1. aa\1.1.3. aac
\testfolder\1. a\1.2. ab\1.2.1. aaa
\testfolder\1. a\1.2. ab\1.2.2. aab
\testfolder\2. b\2.1. aa\2.1.1. aaa
\testfolder\2. b\2.1. aa\2.2.2. aab
```

simply said i want to name a directory "x. name" and the folders in it "x.x. name" where x is a number

**EDIT 1** : i worked around the problem by calculating the path names and putting those in an array and then renaming the directories after the filepath.Walk() function has finished

```
func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) (error) {
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if !f.IsDir() {
    return nil
}
str := path
if str == config.Path {
    return nil
}
dir := str
dir = strings.TrimPrefix(str, filepath.Dir("C:\\Users\\Mark\\Desktop\\testfolder\\"))
slashes := strings.Count(dir, "\\")
if slashes < config.PrevSlashes {
    x := len(config.Slashes) - 1
    for x > slashes {
        config.Slashes[x] = 0
        x--
    }
}
config.Slashes[slashes]++
config.PrevSlashes = slashes
prename := ""
for k, v := range config.Slashes {
    if k != 0 {
        if k <= slashes {
            prename += strconv.Itoa(v) + "."
        }
    }
}
myRegex := `(\\(?P<number>[\d\.]*))  \w`
for i := 0; i < slashes-1; i++ {
    myRegex += `(\\(?P<number` + strconv.Itoa(i) + `>[\d\.]*))  \w*`
}
re := regexp.MustCompile(myRegex)
for i, match := range re.FindAllString(dir, -1) {
    config.Dirpaths[slashes] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", f.Name())
    return nil
    fmt.Println(i, match)
}
config.Dirpaths[slashes] = fmt.Sprintf("%s  %s", prename, f.Name())
prenameOld := ""
for k, v := range config.Dirpaths {
    if k != 0 {
        if v != "" {
            if k == slashes {
                break
            }
            prenameOld += v + "\\"
        }
    }
}
oldname := strings.TrimRight(config.Path+prenameOld+f.Name(), "\\")
newName := strings.TrimRight(config.Path+prenameOld+config.Dirpaths[slashes], "\\")
if len(config.OldNames) != config.MaxDir {
    config.OldNames = append(config.OldNames, oldname)
    config.NewNames = append(config.NewNames, newName)
}
return nil
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want the renames to be, this is not at all clear right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/path.go#L355) for `filepath.Walk`, you'll see that it does the following:

- get **sorted** listed of names for the current directory
- for each name:

  - call your callback function
  - call `walk(name)`

With your given directories, the first call inside `testfolder` will be for `testfolder/a` since `testfolder/1` does not yet exist.

No matter what you do, `Walk` will not reread `testfolder/`, so it will never see the new `1. a` subdirectory.

Renaming dirs/files during `Walk` is a great way to get the wrong behavior.
Instead, I would recommend you list files in the directories yourself and do your own recursion.

Something along the lines of:

- pick next `dir` to process (by default, `testfolder`)
- read current subdirectories/files of `dir` using [File.ReadDirNames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames)
- for each entry:

  - rename as needed
  - add new name to list of directories to process

This uses iteration. Alternatively, you can recurse on the new name (this is where `filepath.Walk` fails you as it doesn't know about the new name).

Comment: Is there a work around or other function which i can use to achieve the result that i want?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion to use File.ReadDirNames and process directory by directory.

Comment: It would be much better to first "dive in"(recursively call the function on subdirs) and rename later. This way, the code will rename leaf directory first and need no reloading.

Comment: That's definitely an alternative. At this point, we're choosing between depth and breadth. Not sure there's a clear winner. Either way, `filepath.Walk` is not particularly suitable.